# Por algum motivo que eu não sei, esse código está ignorando a parte complexa do gráfico sendo que eu preciso dela. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Tags: python, gráfico

```
from qutip import*    
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import cmath

#Definitions    
omega=4    
gamma=omega/4

#parameters
E1=-1/2    
E2=5/2    
E3=-1/2    
w=1    
psi0=basis(3,2)
d1=basis(3,0).dag()*qeye(3) 
d2=qeye(3)*basis(3,1)    
d3=basis(3,2).dag()*qeye(3)


#Hamiltonians' terms    
ET=E1 * d1.dag() * d1+E2*d2.dag() * d2+E3*d3.dag()*d3    
AO=omega*d1.dag()*d3 
SC=gamma*d1.dag()*d2.dag()  
ETC=E1 * d1.dag() * d1+E2*d2.dag() * d2+E3*d3.dag()*d3    
AOC=omega*d3.dag()*d1  
SCC=gamma*d2*d1

#Hamiltonians
H=ET+AO+SC+ETC+AOC+SCC

#X axis
times=np.linspace(0,20,100000)

#Solution    
result=mesolve(H, psi0, times, [], [AO,AOC])

#graph    
fig, ax= plt.subplots()
ax.plot(result.times, result.expect[0]);   
ax.plot(result.times, result.expect[1]); 
ax.set_xlabel('Time');
ax.set_ylabel('Expectation values');    
plt.show(fig)
```

Comment: tem mensagem de erro?

Comment: complexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

Comment: coloca isso no topico, e de preferencia a mensagem complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu caso `result` é uma instância da classe `Result` que armazena o resultado das simulações, essa classe tem o atributo `expect` que é uma `lista/array`, como você tem um array de números complexos você pode acessar as partes reais e imaginárias com `.real` e `.imag`

```
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(result.times, result.expect[1].real )
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('Re x(t)')
plt.title(r'Real part')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(result.times, result.expect[1].imag)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('Im x(t)')
plt.title(r'Imaginary part')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Que resultará em

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]